# vaadin readding component creates new element in dom

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin when readding a component that was removed previously will create a new element in the DOM.

Lets look at it in detail

```java
Button button = new Button("test");
button.getElement().executeJs("""
                this.addEventListener("click", event => {
                    alert("hello");
                });
                """);
add(button);
```

now after some event on the server we decide to remove the component from the view. So the corresponding element in the DOM gets removed.

then after another event we add the button component again. so vaadin creates a new Element on the client and adds this to the DOM. (the new element is missing the eventlistener)

What I would expect to happen is that vaadin reuses the same element that existed before. But it does not. normally this would not really matter, but in our case we added a eventlistener with js. (yes we could add eventlisteners on the javaside, but let’s suppose that we really need to do it in js because we want to execute some code on the client)

why is vaadin doing this, and is there an option so vaadin uses always the same element.
In pure JS I could easily just create a lookup table with the element that I removed, and then later use the elements in the lookup table to add them again to the DOM. Doing this would keep all the event listeners for the element.

What really perplexes me, is that even though the element in the DOM is different everytime, the Element I get with `component.getElement()` is always the same. Isn’t this element supposed to represent the element on the clientside?

Of course we could just run the same js on the element everytime we add the element to the view, but that is quite cumbersome.

Is vaadin doing this because of performance reasons. What are your explanations for this behaviour?

Comment: "executeJs" is a run-once command on the server, not a "I run everytime I'm re-attached on the client side". To archive that, you have to add the call in an attach listener of the component or by overriding the onAttach method. Once a component is removed from the client side, it's deleted - there is no "attaching" again. Adding it from the server side "again" creates a new instance on the client.

Comment: @Knoobie yes I know, but that is not what I asked about. What I asked was, why the client side component is not the same after adding the component again. In javascript its perfectly fine to remove a component from the DOM and later adding it again, with all the event listeners still attached. I don’t know why vaadin creates a new component on the client side. thats where the confusion comes from. that the js only runs once is very obvious to me.

Comment: How should the client know that you removed the component for good and don't wanna reattach? Based on some garbage collection logic on the server side? That's way more complicated and error prone. Leaving the client side with way more memory usage. If you wanna workaround this, instead of removal hiding the component (setVisible(false)) allows to re-use the same client side element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a mechanism to avoid leaking memory. A mechanism based on server-side reference tracking would be significantly more complex, work with a delay (because the reference is cleared only when GC runs), and make it more difficult for the developer to control what happens. The current design makes it easy for the developer to choose what should happen: hide to preserve it in the browser, detach to let it be garbage collected.

I could also clarify that the same DOM element is reused in cases when the component is detached and then attached back again during the same server visit.